# How do you call a jQuery function on a ReactJS element from .jsx script?

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs

I've just started learning ReactJS and there's this thing that occurred to me.

For example:

The function that I would like to execute against a reactjs element:

```
function initializeInput(selector, color) {
    // just an example function
    $(selector).css("font-size", "21pt");
}
```

And a part of my `.jsx` file:

```
var myInput = React.createClass({
componentDidMount: function () {
    initializeInput("#" + this.props.inputId);
},
render: function() {
    return (
        <input type="text" value="text goes here" 
               name={this.props.inputName} 
               id={this.props.inputId}/>
    );
}
});
```

This function is called successfully, however nothing happens and it seems that things don't just work out that way with jQuery and React. Is it even good to mix them up like that? Thanks.

Comment: examine $('selector') it might be empty

Comment: When I log it in the console it is the appropriate selector...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Jquery works very well with Reactjs .
You can call jquery function after react render ie in componentDidMount and

You can react refs for that. Lets say you want a tooltip

```
var myInput = React.createClass({
componentDidMount: function () {
    $(this.refs.tooltip).tooltip();
},
render: function() {
    return (
        <input ref="tooltip" type="text" value="text goes here" 
               name={this.props.inputName} 
               id={this.props.inputId}/>
    );
}
});
```

Comment: Can you demonstrate with some example code, please?

Comment: I get an error saying `findDOMNode()` is not a function, strange :(

Comment: just remove react.findDomnode its been deprecated

Comment: Thank for noting that out! I will accept your answer since you were the first one to write it. However can you explain why do I have to use `refs` instead of selecting the items with a regular css selector?

Comment: Generally not recommended in react. Using refs ( they are just dom nodes)
are the best way to access dom value

Answer (score 2):

First you need to render component elements (`render` function) then call your jquery code in `componentDidMount` handler

http://jsbin.com/zupagav/1/edit?js,console,output

Answer (score 2):

I believe using `this.refs` is the way. I don't think you should need `React.findDomNode`. More about refs from [the React docs](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/more-about-refs.html).

```
var myInput = React.createClass({
  componentDidMount: function () {
    initializeInput(this.refs.inputId);
  },

  render: function() {
    return (
      <input 
        ref="myInput"
        type="text" 
        value="text goes here" 
        name={this.props.inputName} 
        id={this.props.inputId} />
    );
  }
});
```

This is useful for use with third party libraries like jQuery, d3, doing canvas stuff, and more.

Comment: Thanks for your answer... I gave it a vote up but since #Piyush.kapoor was first I think it is fair that he gets the accepted answer.

Comment: I have a .js file in my public folder how do I call the function in that file from a component using jQuery?